# Mailchimp Custom fields not syncing when using Amazon Web Services CDN in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, aws, mailchimp

I'm using Magento 2.2.5 and I've added the custom fields in the Customer Registration page and when a new Customer register and select subscribe to Newsletter then the **Customer Name, Email, Custom fields data** is synced successfully with the MailChimp account and I can see them in MailChimp account.

**Issue**

When I use the AWS CDN for the Static Files and Change the Static File URL from the back-end then on New Customer Registration only email Id is Synced to the MailChimp Account the **Customer First-name, Last-name and Custom field** options do not sync.

Can someone help me in resolving this Issue?